# Red colored font in code

Tags: scoping

To avoid affecting lamda in other part of my notebook, I have wrapped code with Module. After wrapping, red colored font appeared.Could I know the reason?

```
    Clear[n, \[Lambda], t];
Module[{\[Lambda] = 5},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[1 - Exp[-\[Lambda] t], {t, 0, 7}], {{n, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `With` instead of `Module`.

Comment: You should not put Manipulate inside another module. Manipulate is module itself and has it own way of deciding which symbols belong to it. The right way to do this is to put module inside Manipulate. Like this `Clear[n, \[Lambda], t];
Manipulate[Module[{\[Lambda] = 5},
  Plot[1 - Exp[-\[Lambda]* n * t], {t, 0, 7}]
  ],
 {{n, 10}, 1, 100, 1}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {n}
 ]`

Comment: You get red symbols when you do something like this `Module[{a = 5}, Module[{a}, Exp[a*t]]]`  and this is basically the same thing you did. It is just that Manipulate under the cover becomes dynamic module.

Comment: Or just make `λ` another control variable in the `Manipulate` with its initial value set to `5`.